# Co-efficient Problem For Univalent harmonic functions on Unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

The Clunie Sheil Small conjecture for the second co-efficient of a univalent harmonic function on the unit disk is as follows:-

Suppose, $h(z)+\overline{g(z)}$ is a one-one harmonic function on the unit disk where $h(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic. Assume that $h(0)=g(0)=g'(0)=0$ and $h'(0)=1$. Then the conjecture is:-
$|h''(0)|\le 5$.

This is a open problem as far as I know, but I think I heard somewhere that some bound for $|h''(0)|$ has been proved. I could find some references online where they proved a bound for this for certain class of univalent harmonic functions. But I can't find any reference where they prove some bound for $|h''(0)|$ in the general case.

Can anyone please give a reference where I can find this.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this question on [math overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) to be honest.

Comment: Bieberbach conjecture, which has been proved, tells you that the Taylor coefficients of a univalent analytic function on the unit disk, normalized as your $h$, satisfy $a_n \leq n$, for every $n$. Applying this to $h$ and $g$ you should get something.